# Thunderbird: How to customize task list?

Tags: thunderbird, colors, css, tasks, lightning

How can the visual appearance of the task list be customized in Thunderbird ?

I need to change the colors, backgroundcolors and font styles of current/overdue/completed tasks when selected/unselected.

I want to avoid adding [extensions](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/chromatasks/) but rather [use CSS as is shown here for calendar events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74842106/3161220).

Comment: Seems like CSS was found for calendar events, but not for tasks. I haven't been able to find any documentation, so one has to search for any relevant post. Perhaps [this one](https://bug202360.bmoattachments.org/attachment.cgi?id=319766) could be useful. For example the one for "Category-birthday".